# How to change and add new web page and content in an existing PHP web appliaction and get rid of design and view problems?

Tags: php, templates, photoshop

Currently, I work in an existing php web application with sybase database connection.

The web site is built using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Photoshop, Flash, PHP, IIS, and Sybase.

I would like to add some web pages to this web application so I take a copy of one web page like AboutUs.php for Example and I determine a certain area inside it to change the content either static (text and HTML tags) or dynamic  (connecting to the database) and its appearence using CSS.

This web application uses a web template with *.dwt.php Extension and applys for all web site pages as the master web page contains some fixed data like header,footer,rightside,leftside,center and this data includes images and flash objects with predefined sizes and types.

How I can disable the template or modify it to get rid of the design and view changing problems ?

Is there any alternative to replace this template with a new customized template developed by me ?

The problem I face now is when i add my content in the web page the display and the view of it becomes strange and some items and elements overlapped especially in the header, the footer and the sides of the page.

It gives a bad looking for the web page as when data is got from the database or any change happened, the web page design differs especially the images and their borders change and overlapped and intersects.

I do not know Photoshop very well as i think to edit or change the sizes and revise all the web application images properties and sizes to know what is the cause of that.

Is there a fast and proper way to solve that problem instead of rebuilding the web application or testing and verifying all objects and items as this will take long time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.dwt` is a Dreamweaver template format, so it sounds as if the site has been built in [Dreamweaver](http://www.adobe.com/products/dreamweaver/) (a WYSIWYG programme made by Adobe). If you don't know much about web development, or aren't comfortable editing the template then the easiest option may be to use Dreamweaver to edit the site, since this is the format it is currently in.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you need to invest some time and or money in webapplication development. It is hard to expain you how to do it if you have no experience in web application development.

So, no there is no fast way to solve your problem.